# How to get Vue to update the actual DOM right away when nextTick doesn't work, from a .vue file?

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

When I have a Vue component in a .vue file with a data member `isLoading: false`, and a template:

```
<div v-show="isLoading" id="hey" ref="hey">Loading...</div>
<button @click="loadIt()">Load it</button>
```

And a method:

```
loadIt() {
  this.isLoading = true
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log(this.$refs.hey)                  // virtual DOM
    console.log(document.getElementById('hey'))  // actual DOM
    // ...other work here
  })
}
```

I thought that the nextTick function would allow both the virtual and real DOM to update, and thus the two console.log lines would output the same results.  However, they do not: it seems that the real DOM isn't being updated right away, and thus the second log results in a element with `display: none;` whereas the first log doesn't--I get this on the console:

```
<div id="hey" data-v-964d645e="" style="">
<div id="hey" data-v-964d645e="" style="display: none;">
```

(By the way, even if I use `setTimeout` instead of `this.$nextTick`, I get the very same results from console.log.  I also tried using the `updated` hook, but the same symptoms happen there.  If I code any variation in a .js file, the problem goes away, but it persists when in a .vue file.)

Is there some kind of optimization or further asynchrony in how Vue updates the actual DOM from the virtual DOM?  **How do I get the actual DOM to update right away?**

Comment: Note that console can update the display after the fact (usually see an info icon). To be precise, you should save the state of `this.$refs.hey.getAttribute("style")` for an accurate snapshot. Does not negate your issue, though.

Comment: I can't reproduce on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/96or4k51w). Are you able to alter it to reproduce?

Comment: `this.$refs.hey` is **not** a virtual DOM element; it's an actual DOM element

Comment: I think all of you are right. Thanks for helping me find the problem. My follow-up is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that problems with either the eslint-loader cache or the babel-loader cache caused this weirdness.  I could only fix it by deleting all of `node_modules\.cache`.  Too bad I don't know why it happened in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

This works pretty much as expected, with messages matching both before and after DOM update.

I think your understanding that the refs call returns a virtual node rather than an actual DOM element is incorrect.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isLoading: false
  },
  methods: {
    loadIt() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.tellMeAboutIt('before');
      this.$nextTick(() => this.tellMeAboutIt('after'));
    },
    tellMeAboutIt(when) {
        console.log(`Virtual ${when}:`, this.$refs.hey) // virtual DOM
        console.log(`Actual ${when}:`, document.getElementById('hey')) // actual DOM
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-show="isLoading" id="hey" ref="hey">Loading...</div>
  <button @click="loadIt()">Load it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm finding the strange behavior only when it is in a .vue file, but not when in a pure .js setting.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've confirmed that the two different calls still return different results, even if called again:  `console.log(this.$refs.hey, document.getElementById('hey'));   console.log(this.$refs.hey, document.getElementById('hey'))` returns the elements with different styles, twice.

Comment: Interesting. On non-.vue file, the results are the same object; obviously not true for .vue files. Try `this.$forceUpdate()` after you set `isLoading` to see if you get the result you want.

Comment: $forceUpdate didn't help; behavior is the same.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the problem. My follow-up is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707415

Answer (score 1):

Please review [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) in the documentation. Of note is that there is a disconnect between these two events. Also note that `nextTick()` waits for the next DOM update cycle, not necessarily the virtual DOM.

This is typically addressed by using the `updated` lifecycle hook, which executes code *after* the virtual DOM has already been updated. If you need to execute some code with the guarantee that the virtual DOM has already been updated, you will want to do it there.

You may also be interested in [reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). This should act as a good complement to the lifecycle diagram.

Comment: My mistake. It seemed like you were trying to perform DOM modifications. I'll revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Please review my updated answer. Sorry for the incorrect assumption!

Comment: Great, thanks.  That document reads, "In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM after a data change, you can use Vue.nextTick(callback) immediately after the data is changed. The callback will be called after the DOM has been updated." Are you saying that part is incorrect?

Comment: Also, the updated documentation has this: "Note that `updated` does not guarantee that all child components have also been re-rendered. If you want to wait until the entire view has been re-rendered, you can use vm.$nextTick inside of updated."  Does this contradict what you are saying?  I'll try it.

Comment: The problem with `nextTick()` is that this will only work for one level of ancestry in your components. If your child components also have child components and you need to wait for these grandchild components to update, then `nextTick()` will be insufficient. If you need to await a full component ancestry re-render, you're going to run into some trouble. You should either better separate your components to decouple their functionality, or consider using inter-component communication (e.g. `emit(event_name)` and `v-on:event_name`).

Comment: In my experience, using `nextTick()` usually indicates that you're not doing something as well as you could be. That's not a hard rule, but it is a good rule of thumb to follow. It's worth re-evaluating your code structure to see if you can make things work more cleanly.

Comment: My example here is all within one component.  Putting the console.log statements in an `updated` function yields the very same result--the virtual DOM is correctly updated but the actual DOM is not.  I wish to show a "loading" indicator (above, I wrote "hey dude" but I'm changing it now to "loading") immediately after clicking a button, then do the real work as the "loading" indicator is shown.  Can you suggest a better way?  Plus, I want to understand better how Vue works--why the real DOM isn't updating immediately after the virtual DOM changes.

Comment: That's strange. Which version of Vue are you running? I can't seem to reproduce the issue, so it's possible that you're experiencing a bug. You absolutely cannot get the two DOMs to update at the same time as that just isn't how Vue works, but you shouldn't be running into a case where the virtual DOM has not updated by the time the `updated` hook is called.

Comment: Vue version 2.5.16.   When I code up the very same approach in an in-line component within the .vue file (`const component1 = {...}`),  the problem still manifests.  When I code up the very same approach in a component in a .js file (i.e. `export default {...}`) rather than a .vue file, the problem goes away.  What could be bad about my .vue file?  Is this a webpack issue?

Comment: That could very well be related to the problem. I've been testing using inline component definitions and/or Vue instance generation, not by using single-file components. My understanding is that there is also some tooling that is used for single-file components to compile them and make them available for use. If you haven't already, I would recommend that you look into whether or not the resulting JS matches what you expect to see vs. your inline version.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the problem. My follow-up is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707415